# Equivalent "format painter" for Mathematica

Tags: format, copy-as

Does anyone know any equivalent tool like "Format Painter" (Picture) of the MS Word processor but for Mathematica ?

"Format Painter" is used when you want to copy formatting from one item to another. For example if you have written text in Word, and have it formatted using a specific font type, color, and font size you could copy that formatting to another section of text by using the Format Painter tool.

[image: Format Painter]

Comment: Could you please elaborate which functionalty you are looking for.

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch There it is

Answer (score 4):

When you have a first plot

```
P = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 2, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

you can copy many of the options to a second plot with

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}, Evaluate[Sequence @@ Options[P]]]
```

Comment: This is very useful. I am also looking for something more global, that can be used with text, code, font. A fast way that allow me to write a text and apply a formatation of some text from somewhere else in a notebook. I know I can create a shortcut, but a shortcut is very especific...

Comment: It also works without converting to a Sequence: `Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}, Evaluate@Options[P]]`

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Just import or re-use a style sheet.

Just go Format > Stylesheet > Stylesheet chooser:

[image]

Click on one and edit the style and save it.

Comment: Perhaps more information on the process might be helpful here.